# How can I add drop down selections to my UITableView when user presses "add" button?

Tags: swift, uitableview

Currently, myTableView contains "One", "Two" and "Three". I would however, like to to be blank until the user selects both a make and model from the drop down options above, and once the press the "add" button I would like the data to be passed into myTableView.

import UIKit

```
var myTableView: UITableView = UITableView()


struct Section {
    var make: String
    var model: [String]
}

var Cars = [
    Section(make: "Any", model: ["Any"]),
    Section(make: "BMW", model: ["A","B","C"]),
    Section(make: "Ford", model: ["D","E","F"]),
    Section(make: "Audi", model: ["G","H","I"]),
    Section(make: "Bentley", model: ["J","K","L"])
]


var carMake = Cars.map({$0.make})

class ViewController: UIViewController,DropDownBtnProtocol, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func optionChanged(_ button: DropDownBtn, string: String) {
        if button == makeButton {
            if let selectedMake = Cars.first(where: { $0.make == string }) {
                modelButton.dropView.dropDownOptions = selectedMake.model
                self.view.bringSubviewToFront(modelButton.dropView)

            }
        } else if button == modelButton {

        }
    }


    ////Set up buttons
    var makeButton = DropDownBtn()
    var modelButton = DropDownBtn()
    var addButton = UIButton()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "Innocent Sheep"


        view.backgroundColor = .white
        makeButton = DropDownBtn.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        makeButton.delegate = self
        makeButton.setTitle("Select Make", for: .normal)
        makeButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
        makeButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false



        self.view.addSubview(makeButton)

        makeButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        makeButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: -300).isActive = true

        makeButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 450).isActive = true
        makeButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

        makeButton.dropView.dropDownOptions = carMake

        modelButton = DropDownBtn.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        modelButton.delegate = self
        modelButton.setTitle("Select Model", for: .normal)
        modelButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
        modelButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.view.addSubview(modelButton)

        modelButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        modelButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: -240).isActive = true

        modelButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 450).isActive = true
        modelButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true



        let addButton = UIButton.init(type: .system)
        addButton.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 300, width: 60, height: 40)
        addButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        addButton.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
        addButton.layer.borderWidth = 2.5
        addButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(addButton)
    }


    @objc func buttonClicked(_: UIButton) {
        print("tapped")
    }

        var itemsToLoad: [String] = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)

            let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

            let screenWidth = screenSize.width
            let screenHeight = (screenSize.height / 2)

            myTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 500, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
            myTableView.dataSource = self
            myTableView.delegate = self

            myTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
            self.view.addSubview(myTableView)
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return itemsToLoad.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)

            cell.textLabel?.text = self.itemsToLoad[indexPath.row]

            return cell
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            print("User selected table row \(indexPath.row) and item \(itemsToLoad[indexPath.row])")
        }
}


protocol DropDownBtnProtocol {
    func optionChanged(_ button: DropDownBtn, string: String)
}
class DropDownBtn: UIButton, DropDownViewProtocol {
    func dropDownPressed(string: String) {
        self.setTitle(string, for: .normal)
        self.dismissMakeDropDown()
        delegate.optionChanged(self, string: string)
    }
    var delegate: DropDownBtnProtocol!
    var dropView = DropDownView()
    var height = NSLayoutConstraint()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 52/255, green: 49/255, blue: 78/255, alpha: 1)
        dropView = DropDownView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        dropView.delegate = self
        dropView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        self.superview?.addSubview(dropView)
        self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(dropView)
        dropView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        dropView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        dropView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        height = dropView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
    }
    var makeisOpen = false
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if makeisOpen == false {
            makeisOpen = true
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])
            if self.dropView.tableView.contentSize.height > 150 {
                self.height.constant = 150
                self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(dropView)
            } else {
                self.height.constant = self.dropView.tableView.contentSize.height
            }
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0,
                           usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options:
                .curveEaseInOut, animations: {self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
                    self.dropView.center.y += self.dropView.frame.height / 2
            }, completion: nil)
        } else {
            makeisOpen = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])
            self.height.constant = 0
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0,
                           usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5,initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options:
                .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                    self.dropView.center.y -= self.dropView.frame.height / 2
                    self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()

            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    func dismissMakeDropDown() {
        makeisOpen = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])
        self.height.constant = 0
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0,
                       usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5,initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options:
            .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.dropView.center.y -= self.dropView.frame.height / 2
                self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()

        }, completion: nil)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
protocol DropDownViewProtocol {
    func dropDownPressed(string: String)
}
class DropDownView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    var dropDownOptions = [String]() {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    var tableView = UITableView()
    var delegate : DropDownViewProtocol!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dropDownOptions.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:
        IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel!.text = dropDownOptions[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 255/255, green: 160/255, blue: 122/255, alpha: 0.8)
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.delegate.dropDownPressed(string: dropDownOptions[indexPath.row])
    }

    class DropDownView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

        var optionstableView = UITableView()


        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            optionstableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            optionstableView.delegate = self
            optionstableView.dataSource = self
            optionstableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            self.addSubview(optionstableView)

            optionstableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: optionstableView.leftAnchor, constant: 32).isActive = true
            optionstableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: optionstableView.topAnchor, constant: 120).isActive = true
            optionstableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: optionstableView.rightAnchor, constant: -32).isActive = true
            optionstableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: optionstableView.bottomAnchor, constant: -32).isActive = true

        }
        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 25
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:
            IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = UITableViewCell()
            cell.textLabel!.text = "dropDownOptions[indexPath.row]"
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 255/255, green: 160/255, blue: 122/255, alpha: 0.8)
            return cell
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        }



        }

        }
```

Rather than myTableView showing "One","Two" and "Three" I would like it to initially contain no values but when a user selects both a make and model from the above drop down menus and they press the "add" button, the selections are added to the table view. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't know if you just copy and paste stuff or your actual file looks like that. If your file actually looks like that then you need to learn the best practice of code organization and clean up a little.

Second, Not sure if you want to add a cell, a section, or what. After a quick scan of your code, I saw you programmatically created some constraints which were fine but I'd suggest with a custom view or custom UITableViewCell to contain a custom view and put your other view related constraints in there.

So let's get back on the topic, if you simply just want to let the user select two things in the drop down selections then insert the UITableViewCell then you can do it. Just need to add some logic to handle it and remember to update your display data when you insert and remove the table view cell. But I'd suggest clean up your code a bit before you add more logic to it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Any advice on where to find material on learning best practice for code organisation?

Comment: Normally you learn through years experiences and everybody have a different style. Devs normally follow the same code standard each company requires. However, you can start by look into MVC (https://www.raywenderlich.com/1073-model-view-controller-mvc-in-ios-a-modern-approach) But you can find bunch resources on code organization. I will post some article about it as well. Just check out my website https://www.asianjimswift.com/